# Cмещение блока меню при ширине экрана 1400px

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][репозиторий на git hub](https://github.com/Misinkevych/work-time/tree/master)

При написании кода использую bootstrap grid и сборщик gulp.  Происходит смещение блоков при ширине 1400 px не могу найти ошибку. До этой ширины все расширения работает хорошо. Пробивала задавать body overflow-x: hidden не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел ваши файлы, там есть некоторые проблемы.

В данный момент изображение сделано через фон, и при растягивание остается у левого края, чтобы оно растянулось нужно применить `background-size: cover;` . Тогда изображение растягивается по всей ширине, но в верстке у вас высота блока вот такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю так не должно быть, по хорошему нужно переработать блок `header`. Так как там куча `position: absolute` не понимаю для чего они

Comment: Большое спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли! Теперь я понимаю в чем проблема ! Сделала background-size: cover;  в медиа все исправилось. Вы правы на счет хедер. На мое мнение там нужно сделать несколько разметок меню и при нужной ширине их использовать. Я так не сделала поэтому использовала позиционирование

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь.